# Avoiding warning message with "each nth point" option in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, compiling, warnings

Let assume I have a signal with a very large number points. Once I obtain the associated TikZ file, I may run out of memory for compilation...

Ok, so one way to solve this issue is to use the option "each nth point" that allows for skipping a few data points.

Is there a way to get rid of the warning message : "**NOTE: coordinate (X,Y) has been dropped because of a coordinate filter.**" during the compilation ?

By nature, the option is only used for very large number of data points, thus this message appears a crazy number of times and I tend to believe this slows down the compilation...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an option called `filter discard warning` that you can use to disable the warnings. Quoting from the PGFPlots manual:

> [`each nth point`] can be used to reduce a huge amount of coordinates from
>   an input file. In this case, you should also set `filter discard warning=false` to avoid repeated notifications about skipped coordinates.